# Multiple default views for sharepoint discussion board

Tags: sharepoint

Is it possible to have multiple default views for a sharepoint discussion board? I would like to have Subject View default for Top-Level and Threaded View for Discussion. Ticking the Default box changes it for the entire board.

Answer (score 0):

You can put up two webparts and have two different views to the discussion board.

Comment: I'm not sure how this would provide the results I am looking for.  Let me clarify a bit:  I have a discussion board placed inside a page.  I want the top level of the discussion board to have a default subject view, but when the thread titles are clicked and it navigates into the discussion itself, I want the thread and responses to be shown in a threaded view.  I am a complete newbie when it comes to sharepoint, so I hope I am phrasing my question right.

Comment: Ah, I see what you are trying to do. That will take a bit more work.

Comment: So is this answer still useful?